# Oracle SQL CASE expression in WHERE clause only when conditions are met

Tags: sql, oracle

Cant quite figure this one out, i have a set of conditions that i want to be met only if a value is in a field.

So if the Status is complete i want to have three where clause's, if the status doesn't equal complete then i don't want any where clause.

Code

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CASE WHEN Status = 'Complete'
           THEN (included = 0 OR excluded = 0 OR number IS NOT NULL)
           ELSE *Do nothing*
```

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, updated title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually simple to only use boolean expressions in the `WHERE`.  So:

```
WHERE (Status <> 'Complete') OR 
      (included = 0 OR excluded = 0 OR number IS NOT NULL)
```

If `Status` could be `NULL`:

```
WHERE (Status <> 'Complete' OR Status IS NULL) OR 
      (included = 0 OR excluded = 0 OR number IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Sometimes i wonder how i miss the most simple of soltions and over complicate things! Thanks works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can translate the natural language in SQL, then, if possible, reformulate.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (Status = 'Complete' and (included = 0 OR excluded = 0 OR number IS NOT NULL)) 
     or status <> 'Complete'
     or status IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you really need a CASE statement, just use it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE where (Status = 'Complete' and (included = 0 OR excluded = 0 OR number IS NOT NULL)) or (*Your do nothing*)
```